# VSTS internal package server with – version-suffix doesn't really push to server, some other questions

Tags: azure-pipelines, nuget-server, azure-pipelines-build-task

**Question 1**: I'm using VSTS internal nuget server, I have some problem while playing with it.

Now I have a build definition publishing to VSTS internal package server as below, where I set --version-suffix as build number

[image]

After build and publish package per VSTS build, the new packages with suffix should all have been successfully pushed to the server - at least from the log,[image]

Yet don’t know why, none of them were reflected correctly in the package list, only  Common.Test which I removed before the build,[image]

**Question 2**: How in the setting I can ignore *.test.csproj for “dotnet pack”?

**Question 3**: We’re using internal package server, now the interesting thing is, I cannot find a way with “dotnet restore” to get from any nuget config, or internal nuget feed, when this supports internal nuget server/nuget.config as “nuget restore”?

[image]

Comment: `dotnet pack` command is used for pack `.csproj` into a nuget package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack. But it seems your donet core is based on VS2015 with `.xproj`. So please convert it to VS2017 at first.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT it's buit on VS2017 latest update using .net core 1.1

Comment: What's the result if you specify  `*.csproj` in dotnet pack?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT from the log, I thought the packages were generated, and pushed, right? I just tried, same log.

Comment: Yes, they were generated and pushed. But it's wired since you set `dotnet pack *.sln`. Did you use other steps to generate .nupkg except the task you  showed in screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why interal package server don’t show the nuget package with version suffix is that the nuget version `1.0.0` already exist before you pack `.nupkg` files with `--version-suffix v$(build.buildnumber)` argument and nuget treat `1.0.0` version is newer than `1.0.0-v$(build.buildnumber)`
. You can find your pushed versions by click dropdown list.
[image]

If you want to ignore some `.csproj` to generate `.nupkg`, you can set in `dotnet pack`. You can ignore `*Test.csproj` in dotnet pack with two line as below picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  this's clear, version-suffix versions are regarded as "prerelease" in vs nuget manager. now, how can I filter *test.csproj from dotnet pack command? is there any article for a look?

Comment: I add the settings in the picture, you can have a try :)

Comment: Appreciate :) how about question 3? can I directly use VSTS in dotnet restore command argument?

Comment: where can I specify the config file in "dotnet restore" step? (nuget restore has the option) or, do I have to specify the sources with -source in Arguments? --- Log: NuGet Config files used:
      /root/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config
  
  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects :

Comment: when I specified with --source https://xxxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json, i got error in log: error : Unable to load the service index for source